# Google Calendar PHP API - Unable to Set Calendar Notification

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am facing an issue to set a Google Calendar notification. I found some of the questions which was posted on Stack Overflow about **How to set Google Calendar Reminder**.

I managed to create a new calendar event but the notification still display as **`No notifications set`**. Please refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

I thought it is because of the permission setting issue at first but it does not help after I change the permission setting to **`Make changes to event`** to the specific Google service account. Please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

I am using **Laravel 5.3** to code the Google Calendar API function. I believe I am using **Google Calendar API v3**.

Code shown as below.

**Composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
    "mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync": "^1.0"
},
```

**Google Calendar**

```
$event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary($server_name . ' Expiry Date');
$event->setDescription('Server Renewal');

$start = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDate($expiry_date);
$event->setStart($start);

$end = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDate($expiry_date);
$event->setEnd($end);

$reminderEmail = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminder();
$reminderEmail->setMethod('email');
$reminderEmail->setMinutes('10');

$reminder = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminders();
$reminder->setUseDefault('false');
$reminder->setOverrides($reminderEmail);
$event->setReminders($reminder);
```

Comment: Did you receive any kind of error message? Also, did you try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) about notification?

Comment: @KENdi, i don't receive any error message. All the event can be stored successfully but just the notification is not being displayed.